# Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot' for Sub-Collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get my sub-collection firestore info. In my App I'm using a StreamBuilder at First so I can get the main collection data, and them after a FutureBuilder so I can get the sub-collection data. When I attempt to get the sub-collection data, I'm getting the response as:

```
I/flutter ( 2982): [Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot']
```

**That's the same amount of sub-collections that I have, But how can I access different Sub-Collection and get the data inside of it? And Store into a variable**
Heres how I'm getting this to print out:

```
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: Firestore.instance.collection('dadosusuarios').document(user.uid).collection('buttons').getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return  Loading();
              }

              final documents = snapshotsub.data.documents;

              print(documents);

              return Scaffold(
```

Here's how the Firestore looks:
[image: firestore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare these variables for individual fields anywhere in your class. For example if you are using stateful widget, then in your state class, declare

```
var icon;
var act;
```

And then after the print statement, the variable documents is a list. So you can do:

```
var button1 = documents[0];
icon = button1["icondata"];
act = button1["activeLevel"];
```

But this would for data of one document only. So I would recommend you to get familiar with JSON serializing and deserializing in dart, that way you can store this data in well structured models.

Comment: Okay I didn't read the question properly. Wrong answer I'll delete this. You didn't post the full error log, please add full error log.

Comment: That can't be the full error log. Try again, there will be more.

Comment: I get this error from null because it takes a bit to read the document, and them after it reads, it prints the documentSnapshot

Comment: Is it because you have the argument to builder closure named as `snapshotsub` but you are checking the condition `!snapshot.hasData` on a different variable, probably a variable that already has data, so it returns true even when `snapshotsub` has no data. But once it gets data, it prints the data obviously.

Comment: Yep that was a little mistake haha, do you know the answer for my question?

Comment: It is giving me warning  to extend the discussion in comments. Come to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214471/discussion-between-ryosuke-and-nilton-schumacher-f).